# How to launch kali Linux installer inside live version

Tags: kali-linux, boot, terminal, install

i need to know how I can launch the kali Linux installer through terminal pleas.

Running latest version of kali Linux on LIVE USB.
Trouble booting with uefi and so forth so I need to know how to launch the installer so I can install on my hard drive.

Answer would be great.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you are facing? The more specific you are, the more probable it is that you get a good answer. Questions of the type "I didn't succeed, tell me how I need to do it" are usually not attracting many people on this site.

Comment: Moreover, questions specific to Kali usage are better answered on [Kali's own forum](https://forums.kali.org/).

Comment: Can you just answer the question please. Problem doesn't matter. The solution will be running the Kali installation from inside the live desktop. I'm not sure how I can do that.